# Do I have to use `trim()` on every `String` comparison, on both sides?

Tags: java, string

Imagine that I have two `java.lang.String` object, one from Database and another is user input. In order to compare them, is it necessary to put `trim()` on both side of comparison? Doesn't it look a little overhead?

```
if (userInput.trim().equals(dbString.trim())) {
    .....
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I fear I may forget to add `trim()` on EVERY place where I want to compare them.

Comment: why are you using trim instead of direct comparison ???

Comment: trim() is not required if your are sure there are no white spaces present and needs to be removed while comparison

Comment: Probably the database side doesn't have superfluous spaces ? If you are sure of that, there is no need to trim that side, especially if the database part comes from a previously trimmed user entry.

Comment: because my user may copy/paste from Excel or whatever and add some spaces, which doesn't make sense in value but obstacle my comparison if I want to see any change is made.

Comment: Can your Strings ever be null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you control database (and nobody is allowed to change it) **you can trust in your controls and validations before writting data on it**. So comparison later can be done in a regular way later without any concern.

---

## BUT

If you are in danger of getting data with extra blank characters (by some edit, or by other stuff).

**YES, YOU MUST** perform this controlled comparison.

---

If this is the case, don't panic about forgetting one `trim()` when comparing, simply create a private method (or a static one in a HelperClass if will be used throug many... i guess.. *SERVICES*?), to make it clearer and don't forget to use trim():

```
private boolean areEquals(String a, String b) {
   return a.trim().equals(b.trim());
}
```

USE:

```
if (areEquals(userInput, dbInput)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `compare` seems a bad name for your private method though.

Comment: @Manu totally agree, I don't have imagination for this, work mates suggest me a new one `areEquals`, seems more accurate and is not an usual method name... edited ;)

Comment: thanks and accepted, although copy/paste this function in every action class seems... if I construct a service I must construct an object for every action class and it's the same. I think the former one is acceptable.

Comment: Not actually, usually helper classes and its methods are static thus call will be `MyHelper.areEquals(a, b)` no intantiation needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite some overhead as every [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) might construct a new string instance and then throws it away after comparison.

Just make sure to have the right input beforehand. So trim the values when you read them from the database or from user input. For the rest of the program flow in your code you can then be sure that all strings are already trimmed.

This will also prevent you from forgetting to put a [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) before comparing the string somewhere else in your code.

Comment: it is better to control before comparing, but if I am doing a server side validation it is not my case. I can do client-side javascript validation but I prefer not changing the data and process them.